# How to split one excel into multiple excel with common number of rows distribution across all the new excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have one excel with large data. I want to split this excel into multiple excel with equal distribution of rows.

My current code is working partially as it is distributing required number of rows and creating multiple excel. but at the same time it is keep creating more excel by considering the rows number.

In **n_partitions** if I put number 5 then it is creating excel with 5 rows in two excel and after that it keeps creating three more blank excel.
I want my code to stop creating more excel after all the rows gets distributed.

Below is my sample excel with expected result and sample code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code I am currently using is.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Zen/TestZenAmp.xlsx")

n_partitions = 5

for i in range(n_partitions):
    sub_df = df.iloc[(i*n_partitions):((i+1)*n_partitions)]
    sub_df.to_excel(f"C:/Zen/-{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("x.xlsx")

k = 5

g = df.groupby([df.index // k])
df['id'] = g.ngroup()
(g.apply(lambda x: x.drop('id', 1)
         .to_excel(f"/tmp/x-{pd.unique(x.id)[0]}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. After making suggested changes in the script, nothing is happening.

Comment: With the data you provided, it works perfectly on my computer!

Comment: Can you please share entire code ie from start to end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to split your DataFrame into 5-size chunks :

```
n = 5
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

You can access to every chunk like this :

##### >>> `list_df[0]`

[image]

##### >>> `list_df[2]`

[image]

Then you can loop through the list of chunks/sub-dataframes and create separate Excel files :

```
i=1
for sub_df in list_df:
    sub_df.to_excel(f"C:/Zen/-{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="a", index=False)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. After making suggested changes in the script, nothing is happening.